# What does "la $t2, out" in MIPS Assembler mean?

Tags: mips

The code "la $t2 out" must be a code to load address into register $t2, but I am unsure what out means?

Comment: `out` is presumably some label defined elsewhere in the code (which you haven't shown us).

Comment: The problem is you have just a snippet, not a working program.

Comment: This is part of an exam, where some MIPS code was given and I need to explain this instruction line, so I will assume that "out" is some variable. I thought it might be some MIPS specific piece of instruction